# Problem with a CSV file. Syntax error at or near "," (PG::SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby, database, csv

I have a CSV file that has alot of rows. Il show the first row because thats where the problem starts. So my task is to insert data from CSV file to a database.

```
phone_number,start_time,session_time,client_status,operator_status,custom_status,sip and so on...
42424242, 2019-12-09 14:01:17, , CANCEL, , , , 1, 0, some name, 2222222, info, info, 242424, , 0,
```

This is my ruby script.

```
require 'csv'
require 'pg'

host = "localhost"
port = 5432
database = "testdb"
username = "XXX"
password = "XXX"

pg_conn = PG.connect(host,port,"","",database,username,password)
puts pg_conn

csv_text = File.read('/home/XXX/XXX/XXX/calls.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1', :col_sep => ',')

csv.each do |row|
  pg_conn.exec("INSERT INTO testing(custom_field_2, phone_number, client_status, operator_status, start_time, sip)
                VALUES (#{row['custom_field_2']},#{row['phone_number']},#{row['client_status']},#{row['operator_status']},#{row['start_time']},#{row['sip']})")
end
```

When i try to run the script i get this error

```
script.rb:24:in `exec': ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," (PG::SyntaxError)
LINE 2: ...              VALUES (2222222,42424242,CANCEL,,2019-12-0...
                                                         ^
```

So problem starts in csv.each. I tryed to remove the "client status" from csv.each and then it worked.

```
#{row['client_status']}
```

because in csv file some "client_status" rows are empty and i dont know how to make ruby skip the empty spot or somehow count the empty spot in, but in quotes. Maybe its posseble to put every row into quotes when i run the script. At the moment my scrip thinks that i want to insert a comma, but thats just a seperator

```
"42424242", "2019-12-09 14:01:17","  ", "CANCEL"," "," "," ", "1", "0", "some name", "2222222", "info", "info", "242424"," ", "0",
```

EDIT: 
The problem wasn't with the csv file or pg_conn.exec
It was actually my sql function that had an error. But the accepted answer also kind of fixed my problem aswell without me needing to change my sql function.

Comment: Try using a parametrized query via `PG::Connection#exec_params` instead of `PG::Connection#exec` with string interpolations - the former should "sanitize" the blank values properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i dont know how to make ruby skip the empty spot or somehow count the empty spot in, but in quotes

The PG gem comes with a method [`exec_params`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG%2FConnection:exec_params) which converts Ruby objects to  valid SQL types, e.g. empty string to `""`, `nil` to `NULL` etc.

`exec_params` takes two arguments: the SQL query as a string and the Ruby objects as an array. Within the SQL query, you can use `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc. (1-based) to refer to the objects within the array (0-based).

Something like this should work:

```
csv.each do |row|
  values = row.fields('custom_field_2', 'phone_number', 'client_status', 'operator_status', 'start_time', 'sip')

  pg_conn.exec_params(<<-SQL, values)
    INSERT INTO testing (custom_field_2, phone_number, client_status, operator_status, start_time, sip)
      VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
  SQL
end
```